# How can I get the index of a string in Python list, which contains a certain character?

Tags: python, string, list

I have put multiple strings in a list with the `line.split(":")` method and one of them contains a certain character I want to find and return its index in the list.

For example:

```
s = "Hello StackOverflow!"
lst = s.split(" ") # ["Hello", "StackOverflow!"]
```

Now I want to get the index of character `'!'`, so the desired output should be index `1`, as it's in the second string. I could not make it work with `lst.find('!')`, as it works only for characters in list and not strings in lists. Probably you can help find a simple solution.

Comment: You have to loop over the list items and check each string.

Comment: Yeah but I thought there is exists a simpler solution. Thanks anyways

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: How can you be so certain?

Comment: `idx = next(i for i, word in enumerate(s.split()) if search_string in word)`. You'll need to handle `StopIteration`, though, in case the search string is not there

Comment: @Marat Please don't post answers in the comments. Post an answer instead.

Comment: If there is no solution, just pass a 2nd argument to `next` being `None` (or whatever you want it to be if there is no words with the `search_string`), so `idx = next((i for i, s in enumerate(lst) if search_string in s), None)`

Comment: @juanpethes Ok, it depends on the personal definition of "simple(r)".

Comment: Yeah you're correct it may not be super elementary. I was also not disagreeing btw, I was just wondering how you were so sure so fast ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @juanpethes I have seen such questions rather often and I know Python well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
idx = next((i for i, word in enumerate(s.split()) if search_string in word), None)
```

To handle `StopIteration` explicitly, instead of silently returning `None`, remove the second parameter from the statement and use a `try/except` block:

```
try:
    idx = next(i for i, word in enumerate(s.split()) if search_string in word)
except StopIteration:
    ... # do something
```

Comment: Why `None`? I'd rather let the error propagate, myself, and I think that's better practice to show beginners.

Comment: Also, minor thing, but why `s.split()` instead of `lst`?

Comment: @wjandrea That's just one way to handle it. Which one is better depends on the outside context, which is missing in the question.

Comment: @wjandrea this is why I originally posted it as a comment - giving a rough idea without actually making a commitment to make it perfect

Comment: I'm not saying it has to be perfect, just that any assumptions should be mentioned in the answer, like for example *"If the character is not found, normally it'll raise `StopIteration`, but I put `None` as a default instead."* By all means edit that in if you want.